# MLP output of first layer is zero after one epoch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I've been running into an issue lately trying to train a simple MLP.

I'm basically trying to get a network to map the XYZ position and RPY orientation of the end-effector of a robot arm (6-dimensional input) to the angle of every joint of the robot arm to reach that position (6-dimensional output), so this is a regression problem.

I've generated a dataset using the angles to compute the current position, and generated datasets with 5k, 500k and 500M sets of values.

My issue is the MLP I'm using doesn't learn anything at all. Using Tensorboard (I'm using Keras), I've realized that the output of my very first layer is always zero (see image 1), no matter what I try.

Basically, my input is a shape (6,) vector and the output is also a shape (6,) vector.

Here is what I've tried so far, without success:

- I've tried MLPs with 2 layers of size 12, 24; 2 layers of size 48, 48; 4 layers of size 12, 24, 24, 48.
- Adam, SGD, RMSprop optimizers
- Learning rates ranging from 0.15 to 0.001, with and without decay
- Both Mean Squared Error (MSE) and Mean Absolute Error (MAE) as the loss function
- Normalizing the input data, and not normalizing it (the first 3 values are between -3 and +3, the last 3 are between -pi and pi)
- Batch sizes of 1, 10, 32
- Tested the MLP of all 3 datasets of 5k values, 500k values and 5M values.
- Tested with number of epoches ranging from 10 to 1000
- Tested multiple initializers for the bias and kernel.
- Tested both the Sequential model and the Keras functional API (to make sure the issue wasn't how I called the model)
- All 3 of sigmoid, relu and tanh activation functions for the hidden layers (the last layer is a linear activation because its a regression)

Additionally, I've tried the very same MLP architecture on the basic Boston housing price regression dataset by Keras, and the net was definitely learning something, which leads me to believe that there may be some kind of issue with my data. However, I'm at a complete loss as to what it may be as the system in its current state does not learn anything at all, the loss function just stalls starting on the 1st epoch.

Any help or lead would be appreciated, and I will gladly provide code or data if needed!

Thank you

**EDIT:**
Here's a link to 5k samples of the data I'm using. Columns B-G are the output (angles used to generate the position/orientation) and columns H-M are the input (XYZ position and RPY orientation). https://drive.google.com/file/d/18tQJBQg95ISpxF9T3v156JAWRBJYzeiG/view

Also, here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('kinova_jaco_data_5k.csv', names = ['state0',
                                                      'state1',
                                                      'state2',
                                                      'state3',
                                                      'state4',
                                                      'state5',
                                                      'pose0',
                                                      'pose1',
                                                      'pose2',
                                                      'pose3',
                                                      'pose4',
                                                      'pose5'])
states = np.asarray(
    [df.state0.to_numpy(), df.state1.to_numpy(), df.state2.to_numpy(), df.state3.to_numpy(), df.state4.to_numpy(),
     df.state5.to_numpy()]).transpose()
poses = np.asarray(
    [df.pose0.to_numpy(), df.pose1.to_numpy(), df.pose2.to_numpy(), df.pose3.to_numpy(), df.pose4.to_numpy(),
     df.pose5.to_numpy()]).transpose()

x_train_temp, x_test, y_train_temp, y_test = train_test_split(poses, states, test_size=0.2)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train_temp, y_train_temp, test_size=0.2)

mean = x_train.mean(axis=0)
x_train -= mean
std = x_train.std(axis=0)
x_train /= std

x_test -= mean
x_test /= std
x_val -= mean
x_val /= std

n_epochs = 100
n_hidden_layers=2
n_units=[48, 48]

inputs = Input(shape=(6,), dtype= 'float32', name = 'input')
x = Dense(units=n_units[0], activation=relu, name='dense1')(inputs)
for i in range(1, n_hidden_layers):
    x = Dense(units=n_units[i], activation=activation, name='dense'+str(i+1))(x)

out = Dense(units=6, activation='linear', name='output_layer')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)

optimizer = SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.4)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    epochs=n_epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    batch_size=32)
```

**Edit 2**
I've tested the architecture with a random dataset where the input was a (6,) vector where input[i] is a random number and the output was a (6,) vector with output[i] = input[i]² and the network didn't learn anything. I've also tested a random dataset where the input was a random number and the output was a linear function of the input, and the loss converged to 0 pretty quickly. In short, it seems the simple architecture is unable to map a non-linear function.

[image: image 1]

Comment: Which kernel/bias initializer are you using?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code you for a minimal network that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @thushv89 I've tried both the default Glorot initializer for kernel and zeros for bias, as well as multiple others (notably Random Uniform, Random Normal, etc.)

Comment: @bogatron I edited my initial post with sample data and a snippet of code!

Comment: Have you tried normalizing your inputs to guarantee that there are both positive and negative inputs to the activation function? It may be that the mean value of your data results in inputs that are so negative that the activation is always low.

Comment: Yep, I've tried normalizing data between -1 and 1, as well as between 0 and 1 and not normalizing it at all, and it didn't really change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the first dense layer with a Conv1D layer and the network now seems to be learning decently. It's overfitting to my data, but that's territory I'm okay with.

I'm closing the thread for now, I'll spend some time playing with the architecture.

Answer (score 2):

> the output of my very first layer is always zero.

This typically means that the network does not "see" any pattern in the input at all, which  causes it to always predict the mean of the target over the entire training set, regardless of input. Your output is in the range of - to  probably with an expected value of 0, so it checks out.

My guess is that the model is too small to represent the data efficiently. I would suggest that you increase the number of parameters in the model by a factor of 10 or 100 and see if it starts seeing something. Limiting the number of parameters has a regularizing effect on the network, and strong regularization usually leads the the aforementioned derping to the mean.

I'm by no means a robotics expert, but I guess that there are a lot of situations where a small nudge in the output parameters causes a large change of the input. Let's say I'm trying to scratch my back with my left hand - the farther my hand goes to the left, the harder the task becomes, so at some point I might want to switch hands, which is a discontinuous configuration change. A bad analogy, sure, but I hope it demonstrates my hunch that there are certain places in the configuration space where small target changes cause large configuration changes.

Such large changes will cause a very large, very noisy gradient around those points. I'm not sure how well the network will work around these noisy gradients, but I would suggest  as an experiment that you try to limit the training dataset to a set of outputs that are connected smoothly to one another in the configuration space of the arm, if that makes sense. Going further, you should remove any points from the dataset that are close to such configuration boundaries. To make up for that at inference time, you might instead want to sample several close-by points and choose the most common prediction as the final result. Hopefully some of those points will land in a smooth configuration area.

Also, adding batch normalization before each dense layer will help smooth the gradient and provide for more reliable training.

As for the rest of your hyperparameters:

- A batch size of 32 is good, a very small batch size will make the gradient too noisy
- The loss function is not critical, both MSE and MAE should work
- The activation functions aren't critical, ReLU is a good default choice.
- The default initializers a good enough.
- Normalizing is important for Dense layers, so keep it
- Train for as many epochs as you need as long as both the training and validation loss are dropping. If the validation loss hasn't dropped for 5-10 epochs you might as well stop early.
- Adam is a good default choice. Start with a small learning rate and increase the learning rate at the beginning of training only if the training loss is dropping consistently over several epochs.

Further reading: [37 Reasons why your Neural Network is not working](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607)

Comment: I've tried various architectures, with the number of parameters ranging from ~500 to ~2500. Also, your intuition regarding discontinuities is accurate when solving the problem analytically, but it shouldn't be an issue here where the data was all generated using the same forward kinematics.

Comment: In a different situation, I would tend to agree with you with the network being too small to learn anything or it not seeing a pattern. However, there are a few things that make me doubt this is the issue here: 
1. I've read a number of conference papers using simple MLPs with the same inputs as me (albeit different robot arms) who seem to learn decently 
2. There is literally nothing happening with the network. The issue isn't that no noticeable learning happening after a few epochs or that the loss simply stops decreasing. After the very first epoch of training, the gradients are null.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "by a factor of 10 or 100", so try e.g. 250 000 parameters. Also, do keep in mind that the network's weights are updated after every step (i.e. batch), so it's not much use saying "after one epoch". If the network did 100k update steps, then it's more useful to look at what happened inside the epoch, not at the end of it.

Comment: Gradients dropping to zero is almost the same as predictions dropping to the expected value of the target - all weights become 0 and the mean gets encoded into the bias. Which is all a sign of over-regularization.